# The INSERT query run on SQL view but not in visual basic

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to insert into a `Bill` table with 3 columns: `BillID`, `FoodID` and `Count`. No primary key because `BillID` and `FoodID` can be repeated.

I run this query:

```
insert into BillInfo (BillID, FoodID, Count) 
values (3, 'SP05', 1)
```

It works fine in Microsoft Access (query view), but not in my Visual Basic project.

I tried different table, and it can insert okay, but not this table. I think something is wrong with violation key, but the exception yield

> Syntax error in insert into statement

And I don't know how to check it. Please help me.

```
Dim query = "insert into BillInfo(BillID, FoodID, Count) values(3, 'SP05', 1)"
Dim result = DataProvider.Instance.executeNonQuery(query)
```

My `DataProvider` class basically can execute any query with any parameter.

I just tried hard code as an example

Comment: Can you show us the table data types for each column? Also are you sure that your connection string to the DB is correct? Can you run any queries in VB.Net using the same connection string your are using for this insert?

Comment: connection.Open()
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery() works fine, as long you don't show us your class it is har to help

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't show them in details. However, Steve already solve my problem. Thank you so much guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Count* is a reserved word in any database engine that I can think about.
You should try to avoid such words in your database schema.

Anyway, if you want to use that word, then include it in square brackets

```
"Insert into BillInfo(BillID, FoodID, [Count]) values(3, 'SP05', 1)"
```

Comment: Yes, I change Count field to Amount field and it works, thank you so much. It's hard to tell though.